# Finding an analytical solution for a quadratic equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve an elastoplastic problem analytically (extended Druker-Prager), as an alternative the numerical solution. I need to find `xi` in the expression bellow making it equal to zero (`A,B,I1,J2,G,K,a` are constants):

```
eq=-((2 (Sqrt[3] A^2 G I1 + 3 Sqrt[3] a B^2 K - 3 A^2 G xi - 
    3 B^2 K xi - (9 a A B K)/Sqrt[(
    3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/J2] + (3 Sqrt[3] A B K xi)/
    Sqrt[(3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/J2]))/(9 A^2 G K))
```

I have tried this:

```
sol = Solve[eq==0, xi]
```

and this:

```
sol = Minimize[eq, xi]
```

But mma return nothing. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eq = -((2 (Sqrt[3] A^2 G I1 + 3 Sqrt[3] a B^2 K - 3 A^2 G xi - 
         3 B^2 K xi - (9 a A B K)/
          Sqrt[(3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/
            J2] + (3 Sqrt[3] A B K xi)/
          Sqrt[(3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/J2]))/(9 A^2 G K));
```

Add any known constraints on the parameters and variable. For example, if everything is positive,

```
assume = And @@ Thread[Variables[Level[eq, {-1}]] > 0]

(* a > 0 && A > 0 && B > 0 && G > 0 && I1 > 0 && J2 > 0 && K > 0 && xi > 0 *)

sol = Assuming[assume, Solve[assume && eq == 0, xi, Reals] // Simplify];
```

The resulting conditional expressions are quite long

```
LeafCount /@ sol

(* {6415, 7236, 3632} *)
```

For specific values of parameters,

```
sol /. {A -> 10, G -> 100, I1 -> 50, B -> 30, K -> 2, a -> 0.1, 
  J2 -> 1000}

(* {{xi -> Undefined}, {xi -> 28.0452}, {xi -> Undefined}} *)
```

`Undefined` indicates that the condition evaluated to `False` for the specified parameter values.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was really helpfull.

Comment: PS: In the assume, I1 and xi are not greater then zero, but the other constans are.

Comment: "I1 and xi are not greater than zero" do you mean `<= 0` or just not necessarily `> 0`. If you know that they are `<= 0` add those constraints. Similarly, if you know any relations between the parameters, e.g., `a < A`, add those. The more you can constrain the parameters or variables the simpler the results are likely to be. See documentation on [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. If their order is not too great, they can be converted to radicals with [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html). Result would then be longer.

Comment: Thank you. I1 and xi are not necessarily  greater then zero, they can be either, smaller or greater. The other constants are greater.

Comment: the fact tha in the solution exists #1, #1^2, #1^3 and #1^4 signifies that it's a quartic equation?

Comment: Yes, it is a quartic function. Consequently, the `Root` representation is much more compact than were it to be expressed in terms of radicals.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the numerical values of the constants (I choice random integers) you can evaluate it numerically:

```
Solve[N[1/(9 A^2 G k)
2 (A^2 G (Sqrt[3] I1 - 3 xi) + 
3 B^2 k (Sqrt[3] a - xi) + (3 A B k (-3 a + Sqrt[3] xi))/
Sqrt[(3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/J2]) /. 
A -> 10 /. G -> 100 /. I1 -> 50 /. B -> 30 /. k -> 2 /. 
a -> 0.1 /. J2 -> 1000] == 0, xi]
```

It returns

```
{{xi -> -17.1861}, {xi -> 28.0452}}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this is not what I want. I need an expression of ` xi` in function of the constants, precisely `xi(A,B,K,G,a,I1,J2)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is necessary to simplify the equation as much as possible, using short notation for the coefficients

```
eq = -((2 (Sqrt[3] A^2 G I1 + 3 Sqrt[3] a B^2 K - 3 A^2 G xi - 
         3 B^2 K xi - (9 a A B K)/
          Sqrt[(3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/
            J2] + (3 Sqrt[3] A B K xi)/
          Sqrt[(3 a^2 - 3 A^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a xi + xi^2)/
            J2]))/(9 A^2 G K));

eq1 = c1 + c2*xi + c3*y + c4*xi*y == 0 && 
   y == 1/Sqrt[c5 + c6*xi + xi^2];
(*{c1 = Sqrt[3]*A^2*G*I1 + 3*Sqrt[3]*a B^2 *k, c2 = -3*A^2*G - 3*B^2*k, 
 c3 = -(9*a*A*B*k)*Sqrt[J2], c4 = 3*Sqrt[3]*A*B*k*Sqrt[J2], 
 c5 = 3*a^2 - 3*A^2, c6 = -2*Sqrt[3]*a }*)
```

In this form, the equation is easily solved

```
sol = Solve[eq1, {xi, y}];

xi /. sol[[1]]

(*-((2 c1 + c2 c6)/(4 c2)) - 
 1/2 \[Sqrt]((2 c1 + c2 c6)^2/(4 c2^2) - (
     2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6))/(
     3 c2^2) + (2^(
        1/3) (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
          3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
             c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
            2 c1 c2 c6)^2))/(3 c2^2 (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + 
             c1^2 c6)^2 + 
          27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
          72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
             2 c1 c2 c6) - 
          9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
             c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
          2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
             2 c1 c2 c6)^3 + \[Sqrt](-4 (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
                3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                   c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                  2 c1 c2 c6)^2)^3 + (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 +
                   c1^2 c6)^2 + 
               27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
               72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                  2 c1 c2 c6) - 
               9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                  c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
               2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6)^3)^2))^(
        1/3)) + (1/(
     3 2^(1/3)
       c2^2))((27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6)^2 + 
       27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
       72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
          2 c1 c2 c6) - 
       9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + c2 c6) (c1^2 - 
          c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
       2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
          2 c1 c2 c6)^3 + \[Sqrt](-4 (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
             3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
               2 c1 c2 c6)^2)^3 + (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + 
               c1^2 c6)^2 + 
            27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
            72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
               2 c1 c2 c6) - 
            9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
               c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
            2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6)^3)^2))^(1/3))) - 
 1/2 \[Sqrt]((2 c1 + c2 c6)^2/(2 c2^2) - (
     4 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6))/(
     3 c2^2) - (2^(
        1/3) (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
          3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
             c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
            2 c1 c2 c6)^2))/(3 c2^2 (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + 
             c1^2 c6)^2 + 
          27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
          72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
             2 c1 c2 c6) - 
          9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
             c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
          2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
             2 c1 c2 c6)^3 + \[Sqrt](-4 (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
                3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                   c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                  2 c1 c2 c6)^2)^3 + (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 +
                   c1^2 c6)^2 + 
               27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
               72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                  2 c1 c2 c6) - 
               9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                  c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
               2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6)^3)^2))^(
        1/3)) - (1/(
     3 2^(1/3)
       c2^2))((27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6)^2 + 
       27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
       72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
          2 c1 c2 c6) - 
       9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + c2 c6) (c1^2 - 
          c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
       2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
          2 c1 c2 c6)^3 + \[Sqrt](-4 (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
             3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
               2 c1 c2 c6)^2)^3 + (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + 
               c1^2 c6)^2 + 
            27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
            72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
               2 c1 c2 c6) - 
            9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
               c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
            2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6)^3)^2))^(
     1/3)) - (-((8 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6))/
         c2^2) - (2 c1 + c2 c6)^3/c2^3 + (
        4 (2 c1 + c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6))/
        c2^3)/(4 \[Sqrt]((2 c1 + c2 c6)^2/(4 c2^2) - (
           2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6))/(
           3 c2^2) + (2^(
              1/3) (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) - 
                3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                   c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                  2 c1 c2 c6)^2))/(3 c2^2 (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 
                   2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6)^2 + 
                27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
                72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                   2 c1 c2 c6) - 
                9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                   c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
                2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                   2 c1 c2 c6)^3 + \[Sqrt](-4 (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + 
                    c1^2 c5) - 
                    3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                    c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                    2 c1 c2 c6)^2)^3 + (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 
                    2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6)^2 + 
                    27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
                    72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + 
                    c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) - 
                    9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                    c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
                    2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6)^3)^2))^(
              1/3)) + (1/(
           3 2^(1/3)
             c2^2))((27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6)^2 + 
             27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
             72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                2 c1 c2 c6) - 
             9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
             2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                2 c1 c2 c6)^3 + \[Sqrt](-4 (12 c2^2 (-c3^2 + 
                    c1^2 c5) - 
                   3 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                    c2 c6) + (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                    2 c1 c2 c6)^2)^3 + (27 c2^2 (-2 c3 c4 + 
                    2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6)^2 + 
                  27 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (2 c1 + c2 c6)^2 - 
                  72 c2^2 (-c3^2 + c1^2 c5) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 
                    2 c1 c2 c6) - 
                  9 c2 (-2 c3 c4 + 2 c1 c2 c5 + c1^2 c6) (2 c1 + 
                    c2 c6) (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6) + 
                  2 (c1^2 - c4^2 + c2^2 c5 + 2 c1 c2 c6)^3)^2))^(
           1/3)))))*)
```

Substitute the coefficients

```
xi1 = With[{c1 = Sqrt[3]*A^2*G*I1 + 3*Sqrt[3]*a B^2 *k, 
   c2 = -3*A^2*G - 3*B^2*k, c3 = -(9*a*A*B*k)*Sqrt[J2], 
   c4 = 3*Sqrt[3]*A*B*k*Sqrt[J2], c5 = 3*a^2 - 3*A^2, 
   c6 = -2*Sqrt[3]*a }, xi /. sol[[1]]]
```

Compare with the numerical solution that got @GaeP

```
    Table[
 With[{c1 = Sqrt[3]*A^2*G*I1 + 3*Sqrt[3]*a B^2 *k, 
          c2 = -3*A^2*G - 3*B^2*k, c3 = -(9*a*A*B*k)*Sqrt[J2], 
          c4 = 3*Sqrt[3]*A*B*k*Sqrt[J2], c5 = 3*a^2 - 3*A^2, 
          c6 = -2*Sqrt[3]*a }, xi /. sol[[i]]] /. A -> 10 /. 
       G -> 100 /. I1 -> 50 /. B -> 30 /. k -> 2 /. a -> 0.1 /. 
  J2 -> 1000, {i, 1, 4}]

(*Out[]= {-17.1861 - 2.22045*10^-16 I, 19.2341 + 1.82486 I, 
 19.2341 - 1.82486 I, 28.0452 + 5.66214*10^-15 I}*)
```

The first and last root is the same as the solution @GaeP (The imaginary part should be discarded since he used `N[]`).

Comment: simplifying the equation with constants is a good idea. But I need a smaller expression as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, it's just a long comment.

Using Reduce `ConditionalExpression` desapears. But I cant understand the result obtained.

```
sol = Reduce[
   J2 > 0 && a > 0 && B > 0 && G > 0 && A > 0 && K > 0 && (eq == 0), 
   xi, Reals] // Simplify
```

Result:

[image]

What is the meaning of #1, #1^2, #1^3 and #1^4 in the solution? I've checked with the numerical results and, substituting the appropriate constants in the analytical solution given by mma, the correct one appears to be the first one.
What I need is to transform the following expression in a more simple equation (i.e. whitout the term `Root` and `#1, #1^2, #1^3 and #1^4`).

```
Root[3 a^2 A^4 G^2 I1^2 - 3 A^6 G^2 I1^2 + 18 a^3 A^2 B^2 G I1 K - 
   18 a A^4 B^2 G I1 K + 27 a^4 B^4 K^2 - 27 a^2 A^2 B^4 K^2 - 
   27 a^2 A^2 B^2 J2 K^2 + (-6 Sqrt[3] a^2 A^4 G^2 I1 + 
      6 Sqrt[3] A^6 G^2 I1 - 2 Sqrt[3] a A^4 G^2 I1^2 - 
      18 Sqrt[3] a^3 A^2 B^2 G K + 18 Sqrt[3] a A^4 B^2 G K - 
      18 Sqrt[3] a^2 A^2 B^2 G I1 K + 6 Sqrt[3] A^4 B^2 G I1 K - 
      36 Sqrt[3] a^3 B^4 K^2 + 18 Sqrt[3] a A^2 B^4 K^2 + 
      18 Sqrt[3] a A^2 B^2 J2 K^2) #1 + (9 a^2 A^4 G^2 - 9 A^6 G^2 + 
      12 a A^4 G^2 I1 + A^4 G^2 I1^2 + 54 a^2 A^2 B^2 G K - 
      18 A^4 B^2 G K + 18 a A^2 B^2 G I1 K + 54 a^2 B^4 K^2 - 
      9 A^2 B^4 K^2 - 
      9 A^2 B^2 J2 K^2) #1^2 + (-6 Sqrt[3] a A^4 G^2 - 
      2 Sqrt[3] A^4 G^2 I1 - 18 Sqrt[3] a A^2 B^2 G K - 
      2 Sqrt[3] A^2 B^2 G I1 K - 
      12 Sqrt[3] a B^4 K^2) #1^3 + (3 A^4 G^2 + 6 A^2 B^2 G K + 
      3 B^4 K^2) #1^4 &, 1]
```